# Small Amounts of Haram Food Such as Pork

Tags: halal-haram, food

For example if a drop of pork oil got mixed into a soup, is the whole soup haram?

The companions consumed cheese even though there were presumably minute amounts of haram substances in them (maybe cheese is just something is permissible, just wanted to put this out there)

> What is more likely to be the case is that their – that is, the Magians’ – cheese is halaal and that the rennet and milk of an animal that died of natural causes are taahir. That is because when the Sahaabah conquered Iraq, they ate the cheese of the Magians, and this was the prevalent practice among them. What is narrated from some of them, that they regarded that as makrooh, is subject to further examination.

[ [Article Islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/262339/ruling-on-eating-cheese-made-by-magians-zoroastrians)]

Can we relate the hadith about water is pure and nothing makes it impure (iv'e heard the context is that impurities were being mixed into a large ammount of water) to haram food being mixed with halal food? [Hadith Link](https://sunnah.com/bulugh:2) (Bulugh al-Maram 2) [Book 1 Hadith 2]